# Assigned To Field - Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate, approval-process, microsoft-flow

I am looking for a way to Manually enter a email address when I am about to start the flow - where as Approval process in flow contains a per-populated Assigned to field where I have to Mandatory assign a email address while building the flow.

Can this be done and how?

[image]

Comment: Which trigger are you using for your flow? You can use manual trigger and ask the user for email address as a input.

Comment: I Tried that it gives me saying - You cannot use this trigger as an action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the trigger "For a selected item", you can add an input like the below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, Thank you for the Help

Comment: If my answer helps, you could accept it as answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Below steps worked for me, please check if it's working for you:

- **Create a flow with trigger "Manually trigger a flow" trigger. And select email option.**
  [image]
- **Add "Create approval" action and set email property as assigned to in this action.**
  [image]
- **Set other values in above action as per your need.**
- **Run the flow and pass email address of the user you want to set as assigned to. And click run now.**

[image]

- **Assigned user will get email with approval message card in that as shown below:**
  [image]

**Note:** The email address you pass here should be the Microsoft 365 licensed account user.